# Libgdx: move img from one point to another?

Tags: libgdx, movement

I'm trying to make an image move towards another point.
I only have the current X/Y and the destination X/Y + Speed.

That's it.

```
public void Draw(SpriteBatch batch, int goalX, int goalY){
    destX = goalX - posX;
    destY = goalY - posY;

    dist = Math.sqrt(destX * destX + destY * destY);
    destX = destX / dist;
    destY = destY / dist;

    posX += destX * this.speed;
    posY += destY * this.speed;

    batch.draw(img, posX, posY);    
}
```

This is my code, it kinda moves towards the object, but it moves past the object to a certain distance and then starts spazzing out for some reason.

The other point is also moving, just so you know.

Anybody can help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to check if the distance travelled is greater than what remains to travel; if it is, you arrive at your destination on that frame, explicitly set the position instead of 'travelling':

```
public void Draw(SpriteBatch batch, int goalX, int goalY){
    destX = goalX - posX;
    destY = goalY - posY;

    dist = Math.sqrt(destX * destX + destY * destY);
    destX = destX / dist;
    destY = destY / dist;

    travelX = destX * this.speed;
    travelY = destY * this.speed;

    distTravel = Math.sqrt(travelX * travelX + travelY * travelY);

    if ( distTravel > dist )
    {
        posX = destX;
        posY = destY;
    }
    else
    {
        posX += travelX;
        posY += travelY;
    }

    batch.draw(img, posX, posY);    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

LibGDX provides actions for `Actors` which make moves like this easy.

If your image is an `Image` class, it extends `Widget` which extends `Actor` so you can easly make him move (even with tons of interpolation types!):

I'll write you an example:

```
public SomeScreen implements Screen{

    Image someImage;

    //optional
    Stage stage;

    public SomeScreen(){
        someImage = new Image(//Load the image);
        someImage.setPosition(0,0); // left down corner of the screen

        float destinationX = Gdx.graphics.getWidth() - someImage.getWidth();
        float destinationY = Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - someImage.getHeight();

        // we move the actor to the destination point in 3 seconds
        someImage.addAction(Actions.moveTo(destinationx, destinationY, 3f)); 

        // remember that you should add the image to the stage here:
        stage.addActor(image);
    }


    public void draw(SpriteBatch batch, int goalX, int goalY){

        // if you don't have a stage, you should call:
        image.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
        batch.draw(image, image.getX(), image.getY(), image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());

        // if you have a stage (recommended)
        stage.act(delta);
        stage.draw();
    }
}
```